# What do promotion quests do? Does it only increase base stats?

Tags: might-and-magic-7-blood-and-honor, might-and-magic-8-day-of-destroyer, might-and-magic-6-mandate-of-heaven

In might and magic 6, 7, and 8  you can do promotion quests, changing your necromancers in to liches for example.

While becoming an undead endboss is always great of course, I wonder what the changes are. Anybody know?

Comment: I have no idea if the other might and magic versions also have promotion quests. Might be nice to include that if you know.

Comment: MMs 6 and 7 certainly had promotion quests.

Comment: I'll make my question more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Might and Magic 8 manual, promotion quests raise your rank which gives you better hit points, magic points, and most importantly allow the character to obtain higher levels on skill expertise:

> **Rank**
>
> The party can receive special quests in the game called promotion
>   quests. Certain people that the party meets will be empowered to
>   grant class rank on characters of a particular character class. Before
>   they do this, they will ask the party to prove its worth by completing
>   a promotion quest. Gaining the new rank increases the number of
>   spell and hit points a character receives per level. This will also
>   allow the character to learn new skills and to learn other skills at
>   higher levels of expertise.

So for example, a Necromancer can only gain the Master level of expertise for the Fire, Air, Water, Earth, and Dark Magic skills, while a Lich can gain the Grandmaster level expertise for these skills. For magic skills higher level of expertise allow the character to learn more powerful spells.

The Might and Magic 7 manual contains the same section, word for word, as quoted above and so works the same way. Unfortunately the Might and Magic 6 manual doesn't have this section, it only mentions the increase of spell and hit points. From looking at FAQs it appears that in this game promotions don't give access to higher levels of skill expertise. Instead certain requirements need to be met to increase a characters expertise. For certain skills the master level will require that character to have completed a certain promotion quest, but doesn't require the character to have the promoted class. For example the master trainer for the Bow skill will only train a character that has completed the Battle Mage promotion quest, but since any character regardless of class can learn the Bow skill, any character can obtain Master level expertise in this skills.

Other related differences between the three games are that in Might and Magic 6 there are only  three levels of expertise (Normal, Expert, Master), and has two promotions per class. Might and Magic 7 adds a fourth level of expertise (Grandmaster) and splits the the second promotion into choice between light and dark versions of the class. Finally in Might and Magic 8 there are four levels expertise, but only one promotion per class with no light/dark choice.

Comment: One additional thing that getting promoted does (in MM6 at the very least) is make training your characters up to the next level more expensive. It's not a *huge* amount, but it can be significant if you do it at a low enough level.